# How to assign a categorical value to a polygon based on another vector layer

Tags: qgis

I want to assign a biome (from TNC's ecoregion layer http://maps.tnc.org/gis_data.html) to every country in the world.  For countries that contain multiple biomes, I want to assign the biome that represents the greatest proportion of that country. What is the easiest way to do this on QGIS?

Comment: What do you expect as output? An attribute? A map? What are you using for the country source?

Comment: Ultimately, I just want a table that has two columns, (1) country and (2) biome.  I'm using gadm version 2.0 for the country source [http://gadm.org/version2].